# how to use each on ajax using onclick

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to AJAX I've been struggling to code on ajax, but i am enjoying it. my problem is i have a looping data where in each has a vote  link functionality. I was able to do the ajax function but once i click on each data it give me one value only which is the first value i am getting from the database. Here's my code:

```
<span id="question">Vote for your Recipe!</span>

<?php $getData = $recipes->getBreakfast(); foreach($getData as $data) { ?>
<div class="item"><?php echo $data['recipe_id'] ?> </div>

<div class="score"><?php echo $data['vote']; ?></div>
<div class="a"><a href="">Vote</a><?php echo $data['recipe_title']; ?></div>
```

my ajax:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    //var id = $(".item").html();
    var score = $(".score").html();

    $.ajaxSetup({
        url: 'insert_vote.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: 'false',


  });

    $(".a").click(function() {

    alert(score);

       //self.find('.score').html(++score);

       return false;

    });
});
```

Vote for your Recipe!

6
Vote CHICKEN

0
Vote ADOBO

4
Vote HOTDOG

I am only getting the 6 score value even if i click on the other recipe

Comment: do you want .a click alert the .score above?

Comment: yes, its actually working the problem is im getting the same score when i click all the link. its supposed to give me different value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove

```
  var score = $(".score").html();
```

and use

```
$(".a").each(function() {
 $(this).click(function() {
   var score = $(this).prev().html();
   alert(score);
   return false;
 });
});
```

Comment: how about if i want to show the value here: <div class="score"><?php echo $data['vote']; ?></div>  i tried this one  self.find('.score').html(++score); but it gives me one value only which is the first value

Comment: var score = $(this).parent().find(".score").html();

Comment: the parent ends up being the span #question element...and inside it he will have as many elements with .score class as there are recepies...$(this) references <div class="a"> and the sibling right before it will be the .score that is associated with that recepie so prev() is the appropriate one to use here

Comment: i mean when i click the vote link text, it should display the added score from this div: <div class="score"><?php echo $data['vote']; ?></div> but what happen is when i click chicken vote link text it displays all on the data, like it shows 7 on chicken and adobo and hotdog, since i only click chicken it must only shown on the chicken score div.

Comment: hi zoranc i think the problem is in here:  self.find('.score').html(++score);, it gives all score on all the data once trigger.i mean it updated all the data that should display only one.